# Remote dekstop connection to virtualized Windows desktop not working

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

I may be explaining this wrong in the title so I will walk you through my situation here and then put the contents of the .rdp file below.

My company uses rdweb hosted on Windows Server 2012 to allow employees to create a virtual desktop and access created apps.  I've successfully connected to it often before on a Windows machine and the process starts with logging in to https://rdweb.domain.com/rdweb.  Log in with company credentials and from there you click on the RDP file and it opens the login interface and good to go.  The only reason I mention this is that I have saved the RDP file on a Windows machine and I can open and successfully connect without having to log in to the rdweb site.

Is it possible to connect via Ubuntu?  I have tried in rdesktop and in the built in Remmina, but I can't seem to get the setting right.

Here is the text of the RDP file that is downloaded, the only thing I changed was the names of servers and addresses:

```
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:0
redirectsmartcards:i:1
devicestoredirect:sr>:*
drivestoredirect:s:*
redirectdrives:i:1
session bpp:i:32
prompt for credentials on client:i:1
server port:i:3389
allow font smoothing:i:1
promptcredentialonce:i:1
videoplaybackmode:i:1
audiocapturemode:i:1
gatewayusagemethod:i:2
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:1
gatewaycredentialssource:i:0
full address:s:Server.Domain.LOCAL
gatewayhostname:s:rdweb.webDomain.com
workspace id:s:Server.Domain.local
use redirection server name:i:1
loadbalanceinfo:s:tsv://VMResource.1.BT_Virtual_Desk
use multimon:i:1
```

Comment: Still have not gotten this to work.  In further research, it seems that this type of rdweb app requires Active X.  Is it possible to get Active X to work on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rdweb app requires Active X. It is not possible to get Active X to work on Ubuntu (requires Internet Explorer).